# Decoding mapi payload-wireshark

Tags: wireshark, mapi

I am trying to understand the mapi protocol. Is there any resource links or opensource project that can help me in understanding of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425493(v=exchg.80).aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc307725(v=exchg.80).aspx


For support, go to "Using the Exchange Server Protocols":
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/os_exchangeprotocols/threads